# Apache Ignite - how to check if Key already exists?

Tags: caching, key, ignite

What is the best approach to check if Key exists in a cache already and if does not - create a new one:

```
cache.put("key3", 1);
```

I want to increase a Value by 1 if key already exists and if it does not - set it to 1.

Comment: You could try to get the value before your code with the `cache.get()` function and check if it has a value and if it has increase it; if not set the initial value. Can you please do that and then comment your success. Thanks

Comment: If I try to get the value - it is failing to get for non-existing key. Is the best approach to 'try to get it' or there is a method to check existence?

Comment: I'd use the try to get method, because I haven't found another method for checking for the existence untill now.

Comment: Ok, cool. I'll do with Try/Catch block for now..

Comment: alright :) added this as an answer for you 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `cache.containsKey(key)` to check whether the key is present or not.
`cache.containsKey(key)` return boolean value (true/false)

Answer (score 3):

You should get an old value, look if it's null, or not, and depending on it, either write 1 or an incremented old value to cache.

But if you have multiple processes or threads, trying to perform this operation over the same key, you may encounter concurrency issues. Increment is a complex operation which consists of three steps:

- reading of the previous value;
- adding one to the previous value;
- writing of the result.

If you perform these operations concurrently, then some of them may be lost. You need to make these three operations to be executed **atomically.**

There are a few options how you can achieve it. One of them is to make your cache [transactional](https://apacheignite.readme.io/v2.2/docs/transactions#atomicity-mode) and perform needed actions within a transaction or while holding an explicit lock on a cache entry. This is achieved by specifying [TRANSACTIONAL](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/cache/CacheAtomicityMode.html#TRANSACTIONAL) atomicity mode in cache configuration. Use [CacheConfiguration.setAtomicityMode(...)](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/CacheConfiguration.html#setAtomicityMode(org.apache.ignite.cache.CacheAtomicityMode)) to do it. To acquire a lock, use [IgniteCache.lock(...)](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/IgniteCache.html#lock(K)) method. Transaction can be started by calling [Ignite.transactions()](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/Ignite.html#transactions()).[txStart(...)](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/IgniteTransactions.html#txStart(org.apache.ignite.transactions.TransactionConcurrency,%20org.apache.ignite.transactions.TransactionIsolation))

The best option regarding performance is to use [IgniteCache.invoke(...)](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/IgniteCache.html#invoke(K,%20org.apache.ignite.cache.CacheEntryProcessor,%20java.lang.Object...)). Invoke operation is performed atomically, regardless of the cache atomicity, so it's safe to call it concurrently even on an atomic cache.

Here is a concurrent-safe implementation of increment operation:

```java
int inc(IgniteCache<String, Integer> cache, String key) {
    return cache.invoke(key, (entry, arg) -> {
                Integer oldValue = entry.getValue();

                Integer newValue;

                if (oldValue == null)
                    newValue = 1;
                else
                    newValue = oldValue + 1;

                entry.setValue(newValue);

                return newValue;
            }
    );
}
```

Comment: I would also add that if `invoke()` is used, there is no need to configure cache to be `TRANSACTIONAL`. `EntryProcessor` is invoked atomically regardless of atomicity mode, and in addition reduces the amount of data sent across the network. From performance standpoint it's the best way to do this kind of update.

Comment: @ValentinKulichenko Thanks for pointing that out! I think, it is worth mentioning in JavaDoc of invoke method. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, please use the `cache.get()` function before setting the value.

Then just store the value and increase it before setting it back to the cache.

If getting the value fails you can set the initial value.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method seems to be to use [`getAndPutIfAbsent()`](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/IgniteCache.html#getAndPutIfAbsent(K,%20V)).

I'm still a bit unclear about how optimistic and pessimistic transactions would lock the non-existence of the object when using the other methods, in order to prevent overwriting an object just created in concurrent transaction.